# Converting current_date to relative day and static time

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Is it possible to put relative/static date and time in SQL?

I want to get results from yesterday and the day before after.

so lets say date between (current_date-2 06:00:00) and (current_date-1 06:00:00). To get the results from 24h range but with specific hour.
Since I'm using it for BI tool, only plain SQL is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
between  trunc(sysdate) - 2 + 6/24  and trunc(sysdate) - 1 + 6/24
```

6/24 means six hours, because in Oracle 1 is a day.

Comment: +1, but I might be tempted to use `trunc(sysdate) - interval '2' day + interval '6' hour`. I think it's a little clearer than using `6/24`, and also easier to construct less neat times, e.g. `+ interval '6:15' hour to minute` (though that doesn't seem to be an issue here).

Comment: @AlexPoole You're right, ANSI is better, this is just a bad habit of mine.